# How to run a loop within a Pandas dataframe to append a column?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe that is as follows:

```
    MID        POSITION
1   22596394       R8

2   22596394       R8 

3   22596394       R8

4   22591549       R6

5   22591549       R6

6   22591549       R6
```

Now I have another dataframe which will be the output after running some code which will look like the following:

```
Position     Usage
R1             0  
R2             0 
R3             0
R4             0
R5             0
R6             1
R7             0 
R8             1
L1             0
L2             0
L3             0 
...           
L8             0
```

I would like to fill out the Usage column according to the logic below:

Wherever MID changes, note the corresponding POSITION and fill the Usage row corresponding in the output dataframe, for eg: in the above dataframe, R8 and R6 Usage rows should be filled with 1 and the rest Position columns with 0. Similarly if MID changes twice for the same position say R6 for example the R6 Usage row should be filled with 2 and so on. What would be the best way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add desired output from input?

Comment: I've updated the output dataframe. To make it more clear let's say the MID changed 2 times when the positions was still say R6. Then the usage row corresponding to R6 should be filled with 2 and so on. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, but 'MID' is not changed in `R6` nor in `R8`. It is 3 times same value.

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to make myself clear.Let's say rather MID should be unique and the position is noted. For example in the above table, Usage of R6 and R8 is 1 because it has only one unique MID. Hope that makes it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
print (df1.groupby('POSITION')['MID'].nunique())
POSITION
R6    1
R8    1
Name: MID, dtype: int64

print (df1.groupby('POSITION')['MID']
          .nunique()
          .reindex(df2.set_index('Position').index, fill_value=0)
          .rename('Usage')
          .reset_index())
   Position  Usage
0        R1      0
1        R2      0
2        R3      0
3        R4      0
4        R5      0
5        R6      1
6        R7      0
7        R8      1
8        L1      0
9        L2      0
10       L3      0
```

Explanation:

For geting number of unique values per group need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by column `POSITION` and then aggreagate [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) on column `MID`. You get new `Series` with indexes `R6` and `R8`. Then need add another values from `df2` and column `Position`. So if values are unique, one posible solution is create `index` from column `position` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) values in `index` of `df1` by `index` of `df2`. Get some `NaN`, which are replaced by `0` (parameter `fill_value=0`). Then need create new column from index - first rename `Series` name by [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) - get nice `DataFrame`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Usage instead of Position in (df2.set_index('Position').index, fill_value=0) given that I want to fill the Usage column?

Comment: Works as usual. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad can help you! Nice day!

Comment: I don't think you want `nunique` rather something more like `(df.POSITION[1:][~(df.MID.shift(1) == df.MID)[1:]])`, given your description. You want the corresponding POSITION when MID changes... at least that is what you described at first, but then you said something about uniqueness...

Comment: Rather, something to the effect of : `(df.POSITION[1:][~(df.MID.shift(1) == df.MID)[1:]]).value_counts().reindex(['R1','R2','R3','R4','R5','R6'], fill_value=0)` or use the clever `index` trick jezrael used in this answer.

Comment: This works too. Thanks a lot! If you dont mind, could you briefly explain the code? I'm fairly new to Python in general and would like to learn as I go. Thanks again!